# How to replace a Widget with another using Qt?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I have an `QHBoxLayout` with a `QTreeWidget` on the left, a separator on the middle and a widget on the right.

When I click on the `QTreeWidget`, I want to change the widget on the right to modify the `QTreeWidgetItem`

I tried to do this with this code :

```
def new_rendez_vous(self):
    self.ui.horizontalLayout_4.removeWidget(self.ui.editionFormWidget)
    del self.ui.editionFormWidget
    self.ui.editionFormWidget = RendezVousManagerDialog(self.parent)
    self.ui.editionFormWidget.show()
    self.ui.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.ui.editionFormWidget)
    self.connect(self.ui.editionFormWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('saved'), self.scheduleTreeWidget.updateData)

def edit(self, category, rendez_vous):
    self.ui.horizontalLayout_4.removeWidget(self.ui.editionFormWidget)
    del self.ui.editionFormWidget
    self.ui.editionFormWidget = RendezVousManagerDialog(self.parent, category, rendez_vous)
    self.ui.editionFormWidget.show()
    self.ui.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.ui.editionFormWidget)
    self.connect(self.ui.editionFormWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('saved'), self.scheduleTreeWidget.updateData)

def edit_category(self, category):
    self.ui.horizontalLayout_4.removeWidget(self.ui.editionFormWidget)
    del self.ui.editionFormWidget
    self.ui.editionFormWidget = CategoryManagerDialog(self.parent, category)
    self.ui.editionFormWidget.show()
    self.ui.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.ui.editionFormWidget)
    self.connect(self.ui.editionFormWidget, QtCore.SIGNAL('saved'), self.scheduleTreeWidget.updateData)
```

But it doesn't work and all the widgets are stacked up on each other :

[image: Exemple of the bug]
<sub>(source: [free.fr](http://hubscher.remy.free.fr/tally/images/2011/01/07/CaptureDescribingTheBug525.jpg))</sub>
.

Do you know how I can remove the old widget and next display the new one ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The most common solution is to use [`QStackedWidget`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstackedwidget.html) and put all possible widgets into the stack. When selecting an item, just call `setCurrentWidget` to display the one you want.

Answer (score 24):

I have the same question as Natim.

The QStackedWidget is a solution for a preset layout.  It acts like the flippy thing in an old diner for a music box. (X-amount of albums in the jukebox, flip through the installed albums).

However this does not solve the question.

For instance I have code I am prototyping with a UI layout, however I want to replace some of the widgets that are acting as place-holders with the proper widgets that are coded during the primary script execution, or is dynamically created.

I am sure there is a simple procedure or caveat as to how to properly remove/replace a widget.

The code I have has a basic textEdit widget in a grid layout.  I want to code a custom version of this widget for drag and drops and then swap it out with the default textEdit.

Like Natim, the code seems logically sound, however the widgets are hap-hazardly piled in the layout like dumping a purse.

Hopefully can figure out the trick to this and repost the caveat.

SOLUTION:

Voilà!!  Found something that definitely does the trick.  CLOSE your widget

```
#  Remove, Create, Replace
    self.ui.gridLayout.removeWidget(self.ui.dragDataEdit)
    self.ui.dragDataEdit.close()
    self.ui.dragDataEdit = myDumpBox(self.ui.centralwidget)
    self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.ui.dragDataEdit, 0, 0, 1, 1)
    self.ui.gridLayout.update()
```

I removed the widget from the layout,  then closed the widget.  At this time the variable I am using is open to create my custom/modified widget, and then re-insert it into the layout

Yes some more elegance is needed to deal with more complicated layouts, but the basic need of destroying a widget in order to replace it is in the .close() method

Cheers.. hope this helps.
B

Comment: Thank you so much mate finally a solution that actually works

Answer (score 18):

Actually, as for **Qt5** at least, there is a more compact alternative to B4adle7's solution utilizing QLayout's [replaceWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#replaceWidget):

```py
containing_layout = placeholder.parent().layout()
containing_layout.replaceWidget(placeholder, new_widget)
```

---

##### Extra hint:

You want to put a **custom widget** into place with this at runtime and you are using **ui-files**? Use promoting to custom widgets instead! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480835/placeholder-for-a-custom-widget) is a good post with screenshots about how to configure a custom widget inside [Qt designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdesigner-manual.html) for **PyQt**.

In **PySide** this works similar. Instead of specifying the source file of the custom widget as header file, you would register your custom widget class in the `QUiLoader` instance used to load the ui-file via [`registerCustomWidget()`](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtUiTools/QUiLoader.html#PySide6.QtUiTools.PySide6.QtUiTools.QUiLoader.registerCustomWidget) in Python code.

Comment: Yes! Worked for me! Fast and simple as it could be!