# Placeholder for a custom widget

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I am loading a QMainWIndow base from a *.ui file. Also, i have a custom widget i want to place somewhere on the form. Currently i put in the .ui file an empty `QVBoxLayout` named `placeholder`, and in the QMainWindow subclass do `self.placeholder.addWidget(my_custom_widget)`

The only thing i don't like in this approach is that the empty layout does not have its own size. I can have a layout with one cell and with a dummy widget (`QLabel` for example) with the size i want, and replace this widget and then add my custom widget, but the method seems too much for me.

What is your approach for such a task?

I am using Python (PyQt4)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is an easy little tutorial on how to promote a widget:

1. Right click on the widget you are going to use as placeholder and select **Promote To...**. 
   [image: Image Promote]
2. Fill in the *Promoted Clases* pop-up dialog fields:

   - **Base Class Name**: `QWidget` in this case.
   - **Promoted Class Name**: The class name you used to define the widget for which you are creating the placeholder, here it is `MyWidget`
   - **Header File**: */path/to/MyWidget.py* is the path to the file in which `MyWidget` is placed. [image: Image Path]
3. Once you click **Add**, the class is created and displayed, select it and click `Promote`. You are done promoting. [image: Image Add]
4. Here is what you should see in your *Object Inspector* panel, the name of the class is no longer `QWidget`, it's `MyWidget` instead.
   [image: Image Promoted]
5. In the file at `/path/to/MyWidget.py` I have a class named `MyWidget`, and the content is something like this:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   #-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

   from PyQt4 import QtGui

   class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
       def __init__(self, parent=None):
           super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

           self.labelHello = QtGui.QLabel(self)
           self.labelHello.setText("This is My Widget")

           self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
           self.layout.addWidget(self.labelHello)
   ```

Comment: Just a smll remark: at least at my installation, the full file path to the library was not working. I had to change it to a python style import and afterwards it worked great!

Comment: @OBu, Yeah. Need to change it to python based import, thank you for for the suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

You should place a `QWidget` in the `QtDesigner` and then promote it to your custom widget. For more details check this link : http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/designer-using-custom-widgets.html

Another option would be to create a QtDesigner plugin for your widget, but this would be useful only if you need to place in into multiple uis.

Answer (score 3):

Well, not having a better solution for now, i ended up with a QVBoxLayout with one cell with a spacer in it:

[image]

```
FormClass, BaseClass = uic.loadUiType('main_window.ui')
assert BaseClass is QtGui.QMainWindow


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, FormClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # uic adds a function to our class called setupUi
        # calling this creates all the widgets from the .ui file
        self.setupUi(self)

        # my custom widget
        self.web_view = WebView(self, WebPage(self, self.print_to_console))
        # replace placeholder with our widget
        self.placeholder_layout.takeAt(0)  # remove placeholder spacer
        # and replace it with our widget
        self.placeholder_layout.addWidget(self.web_view)
```